# AppCompatActivity with normal fragments and support fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am using the latest AppCompatActivity (`android.support.v7.app`) and in the MainActivity, I am using the normal `Fragment(android.app.Fragment)` and `getFragmentManager`(instead of `getSupportFragmentManager`).

Anyone aware of any problems if we mix `Fragments` from support library?

I am facing some weird behavior in my application as posted in below question?

[Android parentActivity not getting recreated after startActivityForResult returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30852429/android-parentactivity-not-getting-recreated-after-startactivityforresult-return)

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to use the one from support library. You will get bug fixes with every release of the library itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you don't necessarily have to use the support library for fragment support if you're targeting SDK 11 or higher, it's worth using to get material styles from Lollipop on earlier versions of Android. This will give your app a more consistent look and feel.

Do not mix fragments with support fragments, you'll end up with a mess!

In regards to the linked question, your activity doesn't get destroyed when you start another one (regardless of if you call `startActivity` or `startActivityForResult`). You should be able to hit the back button and return to the previous activity, unless you call `finish` on your first activity.

Comment: Thanks Philio for your inputs. For the other question, my issue is whether the activity will get recreated and onActivityResult will be called, if it gets destroyed after a startActivityForResult call?

Comment: Probably would make more sense to answer you other question, I'll post an answer there.