# REQUEST DENIED with Google Places API KEY for Server Web used in an Android application

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

I'm trying to get info from the API of Google Places for an Android application. To do that, first I have enabled this API in my Google Account.

[image]

[image]

Second, I have created an API KEY for Browser. I already have an API KEY Server due to another API.

[image]

So, in my code I have been tested with these two Keys and with both I've got always the same result!!!

> {
>
> "error_message" : "This service requires an API key.",
>
> "html_attributions" : [],
>
> "results" : [],
>
> "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
>
> }

The code that I'm using to make the call are ...

```
        @Override
    protected String doInBackground(LocationService... ls) {
        JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
        URL url;
        HttpsURLConnection urlConnection;

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            //Define connection
            url = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json");
            urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);

            //Send data
            String parameters = "?location=" + String.valueOf(ls[0].getLocation().getLatitude()) + "," + String.valueOf(ls[0].getLocation().getLongitude());
            parameters+="&radius=5000";
            parameters+="&types=restaurant|health|city_hall|gas_station|shopping_mall|grocery_or_supermarket";
            parameters+="&sensor=false";
            parameters+="&key=" + Constants.API_KEY_BROWSER_APPLICATIONS;
            byte[] postData = parameters.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            int postDataLength = postData.length;
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postDataLength));
            DataOutputStream data = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            data.write(postData);
            data.flush();
            data.close();

            Log.d(TAG, "Datos enviados");
            Log.d(TAG, "ResponseCode: " + String.valueOf(urlConnection.getResponseCode()));

            //Display what returns POST request

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            int HttpResult = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

            if(HttpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                String json;

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(),"utf-8"));

                String line;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }

                br.close();

                //System.out.println(""+sb.toString());
                Log.d(TAG, "json: " + sb.toString());

                FileService file = new FileService();
                file.writeLog(POIActivity.TAG, getClass().getName(), POIActivity.urlConnection + parameters);
                file.writeLog(POIActivity.TAG, "doInBackground", sb.toString());

                // Parse the String to a JSON Object
                result = new JSONObject(sb.toString());

            }else{
                //System.out.println(urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
                Log.d(TAG, "urlConnection.getResponseMessage(): " + urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
                result = null;
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, "UnsuppoertedEncodingException: " + e.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, "Error JSONException: " + e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, "IOException: " + e.toString());
        }

        // Return JSON Object
        return result.toString();


    }
```

When I make the call to the API I've got like ResponseCode = 200 and the call that I build is finally like that ...

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=38.26790166666667,-0.7052183333333333&radius=5000&types=restaurant|health|city_hall|gas_station|shopping_mall|grocery_or_supermarket&sensor=false&key=API_KEY
```

Remember, like API_KEY I have used both, Api Key for server applications and Api Key for browser applications and I've got the same result with both.

Sincerely, I'm desperate with this problem because I don't know what I am doing wrong!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are not using the `Google Places API for Android`, you are using the `Google Places API Web Service`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30852429/android-parentactivity-not-getting-recreated-after-startactivityforresult-return/30947712#30947712) is an example of using `Google Places API for Android`, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30161395/im-trying-to-search-nearby-places-such-as-banks-restaurants-atms-inside-the-d/30162174#30162174) is an example of using the `Google Places API Web Service`.  You are definitely using the latter.

Enable the `Google Places API Web Service` and it will work:

If you go to this link while signed into your Google Cloud Console account:
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library?filter=category:maps

This is the API that should be enabled:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Nugent!!! I have enabled my Google Places API Web Service and ... still doesn't work!!! I think your are right, I have to use Google Places API Web Service and maybe there is something wrong in my code. To make the test I have used API Key Server and API Key Browser

Comment: Note that the documentation says that you need to use a Server Key, but I've used it with a Browser Key and it has also worked.  Here is the documentation: https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/intro

Comment: Yeees!!! I have launched this url https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=38.26790166666667,-0.7052183333333333&radius=5000&types=restaurant|health|city_hall|gas_station|shopping_mall|grocery_or_supermarket&sensor=false&key=API_KEY_SERVER with my API KEY Server on my browser and it works!!! But, If I try to get information through my Android application it doesn't work!!! :(

Comment: The error is the same:  {
    "error_message" : "This service requires an API key.",
    "html_attributions" : [],
    "results" : [],
    "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
    }

Comment: Solved!!! I have modified my method to dowload data from Google Places API Web Service for the method that you recomend [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30161395/im-trying-to-search-nearby-places-such-as-banks-restaurants-atms-inside-the-d/30162174#30162174) You have saved my life!! Thank you very much @Daniel Nugent!!!

Comment: That is marvellous! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> Note: You need an Android API key, not a browser key. You can use the same API key for your Google Maps Android API v2 apps and your Google Places API for Android apps.

Check [this](https://developers.google.com/places/android/start) for more help.

Comment: Thanks but ... I just did a test with the Android API Key and does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

For an easier way try latest GCM configuration file implementation and easily create project using their developer interface.

[Enable Google services for your app](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=gcm&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fcloud-messaging%2Fandroid%2Fclient&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20GCM%20Support&%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue)