# Android code to find near by locations

Tags: android, json

i  need small help here in key what key i need to be placed google maps key r browser key?

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
                        sb.append("location="+mLatitude+","+mLongitude);
                        sb.append("&radius=5000");
                        sb.append("&types="+type);
                        sb.append("&sensor=true");
                        sb.append("&key="");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31011216/solved-request-denied-with-google-places-api-key-for-server-web-used-in-an-andr/

Comment: it means i need to pass browser key value??

Comment: Use a Server Key, that's what the documentation says to use.  Also make sure that the correct API is enabled.  Also take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30161395/im-trying-to-search-nearby-places-such-as-banks-restaurants-atms-inside-the-d/30162174#30162174

Answer (score 0):

For the Google Maps API, you do need to give a `key` value. This is where you should put your application's API key. You can create an API key at the [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/).

Source: [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search)