# Google Places Api Key Not authorized

Tags: android, api, google-api, google-places

I am using google places in android app and i am getting this error

```
{
   "error_message" : "This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure that this API is activated in the APIs Console: Learn more: https://code.google.com/apis/console",
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

I have tried using Android key ,browser key and server key but this is not working please help me out I dont know whats wrong with the key...!!
Please Help me
URL that i am using is:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?radius=50&sensor=true&key=<my key>&location=22,75
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31011216/solved-request-denied-with-google-places-api-key-for-server-web-used-in-an-andr

Comment: @DanielNugent still got the same error

Comment: Have you enabled `Google Places API Web Service` in your developer console?

Comment: Your link works for me now, so I guess your problem is solved.  In the future, never post your API key.

Comment: yep i will edit this post and remove my key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the following link to get the google map key registered

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

and make sure that you have enabled the api from  api and auth,

also while providing the sha1 key and your app package name,provide valid data.

Hope it might help

Comment: Just to note, the API in this question requires a server key, there is no need to specify a sha1 value or package name.

Comment: @user3508256 yep, I've used it with a browser key myself as well, and it's worked fine! Though the documentation says to only use it with a server key.

Answer (score 3):

> To ensure that are you enable valid API for Valid Key.

**Note:- 
Enable place api for Browser api server - browser key.
       place api for android key    - android key**

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have '**Google Places API Web Service**' enable (on your Google Api Console, https://console.developers.google.com ). You must use a **Server Key** (not an Android key)

[image: Enable api]

[image: set credentials]

Answer (score 0):

"status" : "REQUEST_DENIED" - Represent Issue regarding Enabling Google API Permission.
    Please Be sure either you are not forgotten to enable API :

Google Maps Android API
Google Maps Geocoding API
Google Maps Geolocation API
Google Places API for Android
Google Places API Web Service

I also facing same problem, But after surfing Developer site I found; it require enable Places API for Web Service too and work for me.

Hope this might be helpful !

Answer (score 0):

`"status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"` Represent Issue regarding Enabling Google API Permission. Please Be sure either you are not forgotten to enable API :

- Google Maps Android API
- Google Maps Geocoding API
- Google Maps Geolocation API
- Google Places API for Android
- Google Places API Web Service