# getting REQUEST_DENIED ("This service requires an API key.") but no error in the API console

Tags: google-places-api

I just added Google Places API Web Service to my project, added an API key (unrestricted, for testing) and I am copy pasting requests from the docs to try things out, for example:

```
curl https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&key=my_new_key
```

I only get Request Denied ("This service requires an API key."), but in the API console I do not see any errors. The key is really in the curl command line in my sample, the API is enabled in the console, the key is valid and not restricted. I cannot find a reason why this should not work?

Answer (score 0):

Here are few things you could try...

- API key is for the application but you should authorize that application in google before using it.
- Check your API key again and see if theres any encoding required before using it.
- Enable API from your google account.
- See if theres any restriction on your API key for example : 
  Under Accept requests from these server IP addresses, enter the IP
  addresses from which your key is to be accepted, one per line. You
  may also enter a subnet using CIDR notation (e.g. 192.168.0.0/22).

Hope this helps..

Try this link.... very helpful 
[REQUEST DENIED with Google Places API KEY for Server Web used in an Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31011216/request-denied-with-google-places-api-key-for-server-web-used-in-an-android-appl)

Comment: If I make an unrestricted key (it shows the yellow exclamation point to warn that it is unrestricted), there should be no other authorization necessary, or do I oversee here anything?

Comment: Also the API is enabled in the console.